# Download file via PHP

Tags: php, download, server, readfile

I'm trying to download a zip file without revealing the URL to the user. The file should only be accessible by authorized users.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
// check authentication and request method etc...
// ...

$file = '../../filename.zip';
$filesize = filesize($file);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: private');
header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
ob_clean();
flush();

echo readfile($file);

die();
```

And I can see the file is downloaded somehow in the Chrome network tab (it shows in the Response tab) and ~3MB are transferred (which is the filesize), but the file isn't downloaded in the browser.

I'm doing a simple GET request, btw.

Thanks for your help,
Tobias

**EDIT:** Okay, apparently I also had an error on the client side and now the file is being downloaded in the browser, but it's only a 1KB zip containing `Response with status: 200 OK for URL: xxx`.

My request looks like this:

```
let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/zip'});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });
this.authHttp.post(environment.apiUrl + 'rewards/download/', data, options)
  .map(res => new Blob([res],{ type: 'application/zip' }))
  .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      //console.log(data);
      window.location.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("Error downloading file.");
    },
    () => console.log("Download completed."));
```

**EDIT2:** Okay, got it. Apparently I had to use `.map(res => new Blob([res.json()],{ type: 'application/zip' }))` in the request. Also now I'm using FileSaver.js instead of window.location, but I don't think that affected the problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `die()`?

Comment: nothing, it's the same. I also tried it without the echo in front of readfile(), but that's the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need  to redirect ur method to your physique zip file.

i mean you need just  to  add :

```
 header("Location: $url_physique_of_ur_zip_file");
```

before

ob_clean();
flush();

and replace $url_physique_of_ur_zip_file by your physique url of your file

i wish u understand me because this solution work for me

Comment: This won't work if the zip file is outside of the document root.

Comment: yes of course, if the zip file ouside of the folder project , that can't be dowloaded

Comment: but that way you could just paste that url into your browser manually and download the file, couldn't you? I want to secure the download only for registered users

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it. Apparently I had to use .map(res => new Blob([res.json()],{ type: 'application/zip' })) in the request. Also now I'm using FileSaver.js instead of window.location, but I don't think that affected the problem.